# PHP Eval, parse error, is it even possible?

Tags: php, eval

This is the code

```
eval("$arr$m = ".$array."");
```

`$m` is part of while loop `while($m <= 4)`, `$array` is an array (itself part of a while loop, so that each iteration the array is different), but what I want to do and cannot figure out, is how to make the eval work out to the following:

```
$arr1 = $array;
$arr2 = $array;
$arr3 = $array;
$arr4 = $array;
```

Is this possible with eval or PHP?

Comment: Don't use numbered vars use an array.

Comment: The use of `eval()` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). There is virtually no circumstance where its use is legitimately warranted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to just make $arr an array of arrays, and skip the eval stuff:

```
$arr[$m] = $someArray
```